# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch in signup page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

It's my first time asking a question here and so I may sound "green" on matters tech.

So, I've been developing a MERN-stack e-commerce project and while setting up the signup page, this is the error that I have experienced as shown in the title

[image: screenshot console error]

Here is the code for the signup page:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import loginSignupImage from "../assets/login-animation.gif";
import { BiShow, BiHide } from "react-icons/bi";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { BsEmojiSmileUpsideDown } from "react-icons/bs";
import { ImagetoBase64 } from "../utility/ImagetoBase64";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";

function Signup() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [showConfirmPassword, setShowConfirmPassword] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
    image : ""
  });
  console.log(data);
  const handleShowPassword = () => {
    setShowPassword((preve) => !preve);
  };
  const handleShowConfirmPassword = () => {
    setShowConfirmPassword((preve) => !preve);
  };

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setData((preve) => {
      return {
        ...preve,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
  };

  const handleUploadProfileImage = async(e)=>{
      const data = await ImagetoBase64(e.target.files[0])
      console.log(data)

      setData((preve)=>{
          return{
            ...preve,
            image : data
          }
      })

  }
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_DOMAIN)
  const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { firstName, email, password, confirmPassword } = data;
    if (firstName && email && password && confirmPassword) {
      if (password === confirmPassword) {
          console.log(data)
          const fetchData = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_DOMAIN}/signup`,{
            method : "POST",
            headers : {
              "content-type" : "application/json"
            },
            body : JSON.stringify(data)
          })

          const dataRes = await fetchData.json()
          console.log(dataRes)

        alert(dataRes.message);
        toast(dataRes.message)
        if(dataRes.alert){
          navigate("/login");
        }
       
      } else {
        alert("password and confirm password not equal");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Please enter required fields");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="p-3 md:p-4">
      <div className="w-full max-w-sm bg-white m-auto flex  flex-col p-4">
        {/* <h1 className='text-center text-2xl font-bold'>Sign up</h1> */}
        <div className="w-20 h-20 overflow-hidden rounded-full drop-shadow-md shadow-md m-auto relative ">
          <img src={data.image ? data.image :  loginSignupImage} className="w-full h-full" />

          <label htmlFor="profileImage">
            <div className="absolute bottom-0 h-1/3  bg-slate-500 bg-opacity-50 w-full text-center cursor-pointer">
              <p className="text-sm p-1 text-white">Upload</p>
            </div>
            <input type={"file"} id="profileImage" accept="image/*" className="hidden" onChange={handleUploadProfileImage}/>
          </label>
        </div>

        <form className="w-full py-3 flex flex-col" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <input
            type={"text"}
            id="firstName"
            name="firstName"
            className="mt-1 mb-2 w-full bg-slate-200 px-2 py-1 rounded focus-within:outline-blue-300"
            value={data.firstName}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
          />

          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input
            type={"text"}
            id="lastName"
            name="lastName"
            className="mt-1 mb-2 w-full bg-slate-200 px-2 py-1 rounded focus-within:outline-blue-300"
            value={data.lastName}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
          />

          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type={"email"}
            id="email"
            name="email"
            className="mt-1 mb-2 w-full bg-slate-200 px-2 py-1 rounded focus-within:outline-blue-300"
            value={data.email}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
          />

          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <div className="flex px-2 py-1 bg-slate-200 rounded mt-1 mb-2 focus-within:outline focus-within:outline-blue-300">
            <input
              type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
              id="password"
              name="password"
              className=" w-full bg-slate-200 border-none outline-none "
              value={data.password}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
            />
            <span
              className="flex text-xl cursor-pointer"
              onClick={handleShowPassword}
            >
              {showPassword ? <BiShow /> : <BiHide />}
            </span>
          </div>

          <label htmlFor="confirmpassword">Confirm Password</label>
          <div className="flex px-2 py-1 bg-slate-200 rounded mt-1 mb-2  focus-within:outline focus-within:outline-blue-300">
            <input
              type={showConfirmPassword ? "text" : "password"}
              id="confirmpassword"
              name="confirmPassword"
              className=" w-full bg-slate-200 border-none outline-none "
              value={data.confirmPassword}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
            />
            <span
              className="flex text-xl cursor-pointer"
              onClick={handleShowConfirmPassword}
            >
              {showConfirmPassword ? <BiShow /> : <BiHide />}
            </span>
          </div>

          <button className="w-full max-w-[150px] m-auto  bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 cursor-pointer  text-white text-xl font-medium text-center py-1 rounded-full mt-4">
            Sign up
          </button>
        </form>
        <p className="text-left text-sm mt-2">
          Already have account ?{" "}
          <Link to={"/login"} className="text-red-500 underline">
            Login
          </Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Signup;
```

The error is in line 58:

```
const fetchData = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_DOMAIN}/signup`,{
```

Further error description details are as attached in the screenshot below:

[image: network tab developer tools]

Any leads would be highly appreciated.
Regards.

Initially, I had thought the failure to include `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` in the frontend's package.json file was the issue and so included it after

```json
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

but it did not turn out as expected.

Addition, here is the header tab information from the "network" section of the console:
[Header request1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGSH4.png)
[Header request2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjxZe.png)

Any assistance accorded and counsel offered would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your server running locally side by side ? Is you have written your URL correct? try writing url without process.env thing like `http://localhost:5000/signup`

Comment: You are currently showing the response body in the screenshot. What is the response status? Could you show us the "Headers" tab of the request instead? (With redacted credentials if present.)